# How use Puppetfile to configure server in standalone mode

Tags: puppet

I'm create puppet configuration structure

```
puppet
│   ├── data
│   │   └── common.yaml
│   ├── hiera.yaml
│   ├── manifests
│   │   └── site.pp
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── accessories
│   │   │   └── manifests
│   │   │       └── init.pp
│   │   ├── nginx
│   │   │   ├── manifests
│   │   │   │   ├── config.pp
│   │   │   │   ├── init.pp
│   │   │   │   └── install.pp
│   │   │   └── templates
│   │   │       └── vhost_site.erb
│   │   ├── php
│   │   │   ├── manifests
│   │   │   │   ├── config.pp
│   │   │   │   ├── init.pp
│   │   │   │   └── install.pp
│   │   │   └── templates
│   │   │       ├── php.ini.erb
│   │   │       └── www.conf.erb
│   │   └── site
│   │       └── manifests
│   │           ├── database.pp
│   │           ├── init.pp
│   │           └── webserver.pp
│   └── Puppetfile
```

Now I have just one server so I sometimes update it manual by runing:

```
sudo puppet apply --hiera_config=hiera.yaml --modulepath=./modules manifests/site.pp
```

At this moment I need to use some external modules and for example I added Puppetfile with next lines.

```
forge "http://forge.puppetlabs.com"

mod 'puppetlabs-mysql', '3.10.0'
```

...and of course it didn't work.
I tried to find something for configure it in command settings for 'apply' ([Configuration Reference](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/configuration.html#moduleworkingdir)) but unsuccessful.

**Is it real to auto-configure puppet in standalone mode by using Puppetfile or it possible only with 'puppet module install'???**

Comment: You need to install librarian-puppet or r10k. For standalone, librarian-puppet is going to make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puppetfiles are not interpreted or read by the puppet server or client code. They're there to help other tools effectively deploy the proper puppet modules.

In your case in order to take advantage of the Puppetfile you've written you would need to install and configure r10k. [HERE](https://docs.puppet.com/pe/latest/r10k.html) are the basics from the Puppet Enterprise documentation. [HERE](https://github.com/puppetlabs/r10k) is another great resource, the r10k GitHub page.

Once installed and configured, `r10k` will read your Puppetfile and download+install the defined entries. In your case, it would install version `3.10.0` of `puppetlabs-mysql`. This would be installed into your `modules` directory and then you can execute the puppet agent run and take advantage of the newly installed modules.

In summary, Puppetfiles are not used by the client, they're used by code deployment software (r10k) to download and build the proper modules for the puppet server or agent to consume. Your options are to configure r10k to provision the modules as defined in the Puppetfile, or download the modules manually and eliminate the need for the Puppetfile.

Comment: Thank! I have installed r10k and now run on virtual station by running
"r10k puppetfile install" in directory with Puppetfile.

Comment: @ВладимирКрасиков Glad everything is fixed. If my answer helped please mark it as the correct answer!